# HTML Tag resets to default lang in some pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

[Html Tag in All pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHyi8.png)
Html tag is having dir and Lang set for all the pages. in App.js
but it resets to lang "en-US" in  some pages.

like this:-
[Html tag in one page where  it is occuring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrffZ.png)

How it gets reset?
Is it a re-rendering issue or component's screen issue?
Is it the library react-helmet-async issue?

This i have written in App.js.

FYI:-  languageVal  changes only once not in all components or screens.

App.js

```
<LocaleContext.Provider value={{ locale, setLocale }}>
        <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
        <HelmetProvider>
        <Helmet>
             <html lang={languageVal}  dir={ languageVal === "ar-AE" ? "rtl" : "ltr"}/>
             </Helmet>
        </HelmetProvider>
        
            <div className="App">{route}</div>
        </Suspense>
     </LocaleContext.Provider>
```